# Read GeoJSON data and create hive table for spatial analysis in EMR

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, amazon-emr, spatial-query

I am trying to read a GeoJson file in Hive inside AMAZON EMR and seems it is not possible. I do not get any error but `select * from table` return null values. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147274/how-to-load-spatial-data-using-the-hadoop-gis-framework), that this is not supported, but this is a three years old question. Is there an update regarding this issue?

Code

```
hadoop fs -cat /home/hadoop/Geographic_unit1/ | head
```

return the output
[image]

This shows GeoJson is in the hdfx. Now in Hive,

```
 CREATE TABLE d (PARCEL_ID bigint ,....)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.EsriJsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedEsriJsonInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
 LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/hadoop/Geographic_unit2/' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE d;
```

and the output is some NULL values, columns are all null.

Please let me know if you need further info.

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Comment: Not unfortunately, Seems no support for this